# Returning list in Python

Tags: python

I'm studying Python and am hitting some Pythonic oddity.  I can't figure out why in returning, this function throws away data.

```
def foo(mylist=None):
    print "Input: {}".format(mylist)
    if mylist is None:
        mylist = list()
    if len(mylist) == 3:
        return mylist
    else:
        mylist.append(len(mylist))
        foo(mylist)

print "Output: {}".format(foo())
```

This prints:

```
Input: None
Input: [0]
Input: [0, 1]
Input: [0, 1, 2]
Output: None
```

I would guess that it has to do with pointing to a list that no longer exists, but I don't get that in a simpler example:

```
def simple_foo():
    to_return = [1, 2, 3]
    return to_return

print "Simple output: {}".format(simple_foo())
```

I've even tried (in foo) deep-copying my list into a to_return variable, then returning that, but that doesn't seem to work either.  Can anybody shed some light on this?  I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to keep `return`ing:

Your recursive call:

```
foo(mylist)
```

needs its return value returned:

```
return foo(mylist)
```

Comment: Thanks!  That's not even a Python thing; I should have caught that.